# php normal distribution of winnings

Tags: php

Ok lets say I have 1000 points that I want to distribute.

I have 200 ranked players to distribute them but I don't want to distribute them evenly.

Instead I want to skew it so that the players at the top tend to get less than those at the top. So effectively I need some sort of function that stimulates one side of the normal distribution.

How would I do that?

Comment: `the players at the top tend to get less than those at the top` typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
function grantPoints($totalavailpoints, $numusers, $rank){
  $pointstogrant=$totalavailpoints/$numusers;
  if($rank>$numusers/2)//he has a higher number rank, meaning he gets more points
    $pointstogrant++;
  else
    $pointstogrant--;
  return $pointstogrant;
}
```

There are *alot* of ways you can adjust this to your needs.  But this is pretty basic. It figures out the average points to give out, and it adds one if you're in the bottom half and subtracts one if you're in the top half.

A few questions to ask yourself:

- Do the points returned have to be integers?
- Do the sum of the points for everybody have to equal the totalavailpoints?
- How much diversity do you want/need in the amount returned in the function?